# Read current incrementing value of Confluent JDBC Kafka Source Connector with Rest?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a Kafka Source Connector using the [`io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector`](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html) class. It is run in [`incrementing` mode](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html#mode).

I can access this connector via the [Rest interface](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/restapi.html#connectors). To examine a problem I want to know the current incrementing value of this connector.

Is there a way to read the current incrementing value with Rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is not available via REST because there are no special endpoints that specific connectors provide that are not uniform across all others (in other words, you only get the /config that you posted and its /status)

If you would like to dig into the connector metadata, you'll have to consume the internal offsets topic. e.g. see this post on [Resetting the Source Offset](https://rmoff.net/2019/08/15/reset-kafka-connect-source-connector-offsets/)